# Keep track of which element was clicked,then read data accordingly in Javascript/Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, user-input

I have 3 `buttons/divs` with ids as "BTN_a.. b.. c", which respectively enable the visibility of 3 different divs with one or more input fields. `BTN_a` shows `DIV_A_inputs`, and hides others.. and so on. The idea is that when the `button id="BTN_Post_Wall"` is clicked, data checks are performed, and if everything is okay, data is sent to a `php` file to do stuff. How do I keep track of Which Button was pressed, and which input fields are visible.. so that when `"BTN_Post_Wall"` is clicked, only those input fields are read. Is there some sort of Global Variable I can change the value of.. e.g. `var Pressed = a` and where do I add this function? is it possible to add some kind of Dummy `attribute` to any element like `$("#DIV_abc").attrib("dummy") = "A_clicked"` and then read it with `BTN_Post_Wall`?
In other words, if `Btn A` was clicked, and then if `BTN_Post_Wall` is clicked, it means then only `INP_A` value needs to be read, checked and sent as `ajax`. If button `C` is pressed, followed by `BTN_Post_Wall`, then only `INP_C_1`, `INP_C_2`, and `INP_C_3` have to be handled. Where can I store this info and proceed with just one button?
All help is much appreciated. Thank you so much!!

```
function CH_ANGE(th, txt)
{   switch(txt) 
    { case "a_click":
            $("#DIV_A_inputs").show();          
            $("#DIV_B_inputs").hide();          
            $("#DIV_C_inputs").hide();          
            break;
            
      case "b_click":
            $("#DIV_A_inputs").hide();          
            $("#DIV_B_inputs").show();          
            $("#DIV_C_inputs").hide();          
            break;
            
      case "c_click":
            $("#DIV_A_inputs").hide();          
            $("#DIV_B_inputs").hide();          
            $("#DIV_C_inputs").show();          
            break;
}
```

MAIN_UI.php file is as follows:

```
        <div id="DV_post_type">                  
             <div id="BTN_a" onclick="CH_ANGE(this, 'a_click')">Button A</div>     
             <div id="BTN_b" onclick="CH_ANGE(this, 'b_click')">Button B</div>      
             <div id="BTN_c" onclick="CH_ANGE(this, 'c_click')">Button C</div>
                            
             <button id="BTN_Post_Wall" onClick="POST_AJAX_INP_to_PHP_BUTTON()">POST</button>
        </div>

        <div id="DIV_abc">
                <div id="DIV_A_inputs">Div_A and other content
                     <input TYPE="TEXT" ID="inp_A" NAME="INP_A">                
                </div>
                
                <div id="DIV_B_inputs">Div_B and other content
                     <input TYPE="TEXT" ID="inp_B_1" NAME="INP_B_1">                     
                     <input TYPE="TEXT" ID="inp_B_2" NAME="INP_B_2">                     
                     <input TYPE="TEXT" ID="inp_B_3" NAME="INP_B_3">                     
                </div>
                
                <div id="DIV_C_inputs">
                     <input TYPE="TEXT" ID="inp_C_1" NAME="INP_C_1">
                     <input TYPE="TEXT" ID="inp_C_2" NAME="INP_C_2">
                </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: It appears that you're over-complicating things.  Why not use classes to group things that belong together?  There really shouldn't be a need to "track" things.  `this` will tell you which button was clicked, and you can do your operations on the inputs with the same class as `this`.

Comment: Instead of showing/hiding in every case, just hide ALL of them before your switch case, and only show the relevant one.

Comment: @devlincarnate Hi.. the issue is, there are 3 butons which enable 3 totally different sets of inputs, thats one part of the javascript, done. THEN.. the user enters values depending on what entry fields are visible, and Then.. when he clicks the one and only "BTN_Post_Wall", the checking and posting is done.. How do I make the code for BTN_Post_Wall know where to go and start reading.. it can go anywhere.. to DIV_A_inputs.. or DIV_B_inputs or DIV_C_Inputs...

Comment: Assign classes to your buttons.  For the inputs that are associated with each button, assign the same class -- so your elements are "grouped" by classes.  You'll know which inputs to show or hide because they're the elements with the same class as the button.  When the BTN_Post_Wall button is clicked, you know which inputs to check because they're the VISIBLE ones with one of the shared classes.

Comment: You can use data attributes to distinguish different elements, and the `.data` method in jquery to read the attribute from an element.